# alter session set current_schema not working globally

Tags: python, oracle, hadoop, pyspark, cx-oracle

I am changing the schema in the main function

```
db_dwh.cursor.execute("alter session set current_schema = SCHEMA_NAME")
```

But when I am passing this **db_dwh** object to a function and trying to execute a query on a table I am getting table not found error,
for this again I have to set schema using:

```
db_dwh.cursor.execute("alter session set current_schema = SCHEMA_NAME")
```

Is there any way to set schema at only one place globally?

---

PS The job running in Hadoop environment.

Comment: see if this helps https://technology.amis.nl/tech/how-to-set-the-current-database-schema-of-an-application-using-a-global-context/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your function has a different connection - I hope you're using a connection pool.

The comment has one solution.

Here are some other tools that are available.  They may be useful, depending on your (or other readers) application architecture:

- [Connection.current_schema](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.current_schema) instead of an explicit ALTER SESSION.  This saves the round-trip overhead of an `execute()`.
- Connection Pool callbacks to efficiently set state: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#session-callbacks-for-setting-pooled-connection-state  You say you are trying to set the schema globally.  If it always has the same value, then I would use this solution in conjunction with the `Connection.current_schema` attribute.

```
    def init_session(connection, requested_tag):
        connection.current_schema = 'ALISON'

    # Create the pool with a session callback
    pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user="whoever", password=userpwd, dsn="orclpdb1", session_callback=init_session)

    # Get a connection from the pool.  It will always have the current schema
    # set to ALISON
    connection = pool.acquire()

    . . .  # Use the connection
```

- Heterogeneous connection pools: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#heterogeneous-and-homogeneous-connection-pools

Comment: PS Prior to cx_Oracle 8.2 make sure to set `threaded=True` when creating the connection pool

Comment: The parameter session_callback does not exist, please correct this typo, should be sessionCallback.

Comment: Various parameters were renamed (aliased) in cx_Oracle 8.2.  https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/deprecations.html#deprecations.  This was for PEP compliance.